# DateTime.TryParse not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, datetime, datetime-parsing

```
public JsonResult TimeValidation(string pickUp, string delivery)   
{

    var errorMessage = string.Empty;
    var dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(pickUp, out dateTime))
        errorMessage = "Invalid date";

     if (!DateTime.TryParse(delivery, out dateTime))
        errorMessage = "Invalid date";
}
‎4‎/‎29‎/‎2015‎ ‎3‎:‎30‎:‎00‎ ‎PM pickup from ie
4‎/‎30‎/‎2015‎ ‎12‎:‎00‎:‎00‎ ‎AM delivery from ie
4/29/2015, 3:30:00 PM pickup from  firefox
4/30/2015, 12:00:00 AM delivery from firefox
```

‎

its working good in chrome and firefox but its not converting to datetime in internet explorer 11 please obseve , between date and time

Comment: C# doesn't run in the browser. Can you explain a bit more what exactly you're doing?

Comment: *What* is being converted to a `DateTime` in IE?

Comment: Are you getting the `stringDate` value from the browser? If so, you should show how you obtain it.

Comment: @Rufus L  string date should be converted into datetime ...

Comment: @Juan C it is not converting to datetime it returns false in my if condition please observe ! in if condition

Comment: Ok, cool. The wording changed since I commented. But this is C#, not browser code. Something else must be going on when you're passing it to java or asp.net. Also, you're missing a semi-colon after the string assignment.

Comment: Edit your question and add the portion of code where `stringDate` comes from.

Comment: Add the code of the browser from where you atually send the date `pickUp`

Comment: You still did *not* show where `pickup` and `delivery` are coming from. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We shouldn't need to prompt you for these details - when you ask a question, make sure you've given a *complete* example.

Comment: @mason i  updated my code. if i am right problem is comma symbol , in between date and time

Comment: So remove the comma? Or use client side validation to make sure that the data sent to the server is correct? Or use a different function to parse the date on the server, or try to parse several formats? Anyways, you shouldn't be accepting the dates as strings. You should use the `DateTime` type and let the framework convert it for you.

Comment: @Cameron pickUp string is converted some other format like this **4?/?30?/?2015? ?9?:?30?:?00? ?PM**

Comment: I have also catched this issue and it only reproduces if request comes from IE11 and culture is set to es-PE. Date example - Mon, 07 Mar 2016 10:09:34 GMT. CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture has same values and all params similar to culture settings that assigned in case if request come from Firefox or Chrome. Also, in my case, used basic or windows authorization of users from AD and I think it somehow related!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is C# (looks like it is) and it is running on the server (not actually in the browser): You should check to see what the value of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is. See if it is different for a request coming from IE vs one of your other browsers. `DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime)` uses this value to help parse the string.

For instance, the date you provided: `"28/04/2015 07:59:00"` will cause `TryParse` to return `false` if the current culture is `en-US`, but if the current culture is `es-MX`, then it will return `true`.

I'm not sure why it would be different between browsers off the top of my head, but it's at least a place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue and the issue was the javaScript method
`toLocaleDateString()` in IE11 return string with some RTL characters! which results in invalid data and these characters aren't visible.

A simple fix using regex

`` toLocaleDateString().replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '') ``

I tried the same regex at the back `C#` but it didn't work, however, I didn't want to spend more time on this so I just applied the front end solution.

[More details, source](http://toLocaleDateString('en-Au',%20this.dateOptions).replace(/[%5EA-Za-z%200-9%20%5C.,%5C?%22%22!@#%5C$%25%5C%5E&%5C*%5C(%5C)-_=%5C%20;:%3C%3E%5C/%5C%5C%5C%7C%5C%7D%5C%7B%5C[%5C]%60~]*/g,%20''))